# How to use non-ADSL router with ADS line?

Tags: adsl, adsl-router

Currently I connect to ADSL line with an old linksys wag54gs modem/router device.

I'm not satisified with it and would rather use my TP-Link Archer C7 with openWRT - which obviously has no modem buildin. What are my configuration options ? Can I use my wag54gs as just a modem and somehow pass connection do Archer ? Do I need to buy new modem ? 
thanks for any tips

Comment: Yes, you can use the old one as modem only.

Comment: thanks @GabrielaGarcia - any tips on how to configure this? One of the devices should be in bridge mode, rught? But not sure how exactly this functions.

Comment: Not sure either. When I have to do it I always have to fiddle with several configurations until done right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a hardware POV you put an ADSL modem on the WAN side of the router, connecting the LAN side to your network as normal.

From a software side there is no single correct answer. The easiest is often to just do "double NAT". The only changes this might require are to change the IP range between modem and router and router and LAN so they don't overlap. You possibly also want to add a route to enable your modem to point LAN IPs back to the router and set the router WAN IP up as a DMZ if you need port forwarding.

Depending on your modem and connection type you may alternatively be able to acquire your WAN IP on your modem. There are many techniques depending on ADSL connection type - I used to use half-bridge mode in a PPPoA connection, but could change thus to have the modem act as a bridge and the router terminate the PPP connection when the connection was provided with PPPoA.   It is also possible that no PPP may be needed in some setups with the modem acting like a bridge/media converter.  You may also, depending on the telco setup need to configure a VLAN on the router WAN port if this is required by the telco delivery design (often the case if multiple services are delivered over ine cable)

Comment: Afaik, most ISPs use either IPoE or PPPoE, which can be fully bridged without issues (configuring the router as a PPP client if necessary).

Comment: In NZ, the major telco uses PPPoA for ADSL (but PPPoE for VDSL). I believe PPPoE is standard in Australia - I posit it depends on when ADSL was made available - early on it would be pppoa to brudge with ATM technologies while newer rollouts use PPPoE to bridge with ethernet.